# I need to write an .sql query that shows data aggregated at the monthly level looking back over the past two years

Tags: sql

Right now the problem with my code is that it counts each month as a new aggregation, meaning that January and February will contain activity for the same account in both months.  I only need the monthly activity for each month at the level of each account.

Right now where for example the activity for Account A = 100 for January and activity for Account A = 25 in February, my query shows activity in February for account A as 125 when I would like it to be returned as A = 100 for January and A = 25 for February.

Is this clear?  If I use for example (YEAR(date_column)) the aggregation at the annual level is accurately represented.  This approach however does not allow me to provide a monthly breakdown of the data.  If I add a second column to get the "Month" values from the date e.g: (MONTH(date_column)), the numbers are aggregated month over month and not at the month level alone.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you, show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (no images,) - i.e. [mcve].

Comment: The best way to help you is to see the actual SQL code that you are currently using in this query.  We can then show you alterations to your SQL query code to accommodate the requested result.  Another beneficial item to include in your question is what database platform is used for this query, such as MS SQL.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Edit tags. Show sample data and desired output as text tables. Aggregation by month would have to include year: `Format([datefield], "yyyymm")`. Instead of aggregating in query, could build a report and perform aggregate calcs in group footer section - at least Access reporting has this. Report allows display of raw data as well as summary calcs.

Comment: Not really understanding what you mean by 'month over month'. If year and month are included in grouping, that should work. Edit question to show attempted SQL.